Show inequality involving capacities of the union and intersection of cuts.
Let $(S,\overline S)$, $(T,\overline T)$ be cuts of a network $G$. I've alredy showed que $(S\cup T,\overline{S\cup T})$ and $(S\cap T,\overline{S\cap T})$ are cuts for $G$. Now, I have left to prove that $$cap(S\cup T,\overline{S\cup T})+cap(S\cap T,\overline{S\cap T})\leq cap(S,\overline S)+cap(T,\overline {T}),$$
where $cap$ denotes the capacity of an edge (its weight).
What I've tried so far is that if we take $e\in E(G)$ such that $e=uv$, with $u\in S\cup T$ and $v\in \overline{S\cup T}$, then it sums $cap(e)$ on the LHS and sums at least once $cap(e)$ on the RHS. We have a same argument for an edge $e=uv$ with $u\in S\cap T$ and $v\in\overline{S\cap T}$. But what I need to conclude the inequality is that each edge $e$ cannot sum $cap(e)$ in both $cap(S\cup T,\overline{S\cup T})$ and $cap(S\cap T,\overline{S\cap T})$.

Something that might be relevant is inequality ($\dagger$) on Pg. 363 of Diestel's Graph Theory: it is this inequality when all edge weights are $1$.

Thanks for point that out!

Decompose into disjoint unions as follows:
\begin{align}
S &= (S \setminus T) \cup (S \cap T) \\
\overline{S} &= (\overline{S} \setminus \overline{T}) \cup (\overline{S} \cap \overline{T}) \\
T &= (T \setminus S) \cup (S \cap T) \\
\overline{T} &= (\overline{T} \setminus \overline{S}) \cup (\overline{S} \cap \overline{T}) \\
S \cup T &= (S \setminus T) \cup (S \cap T) \cup (T \setminus S) \\
\overline{S \cap T} &= (\overline{S} \setminus \overline{T}) \cup (\overline{S} \cap \overline{T}) \cup (\overline{T} \setminus \overline{S})
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
& \operatorname{cap}(S\cup T,\overline{S\cup T}) + \operatorname{cap}(S\cap T,\overline{S\cap T}) \\
&= \operatorname{cap}(S\cup T,\overline{S}\cap \overline{T}) + \operatorname{cap}(S\cap T,\overline{S\cap T}) \\
&= \operatorname{cap}(S\setminus T,\overline{S}\cap \overline{T}) + \operatorname{cap}(S\cap T,\overline{S}\cap \overline{T}) + \operatorname{cap}(T\setminus S,\overline{S}\cap \overline{T}) \\
&+ \operatorname{cap}(S\cap T,\overline{S} \setminus \overline{T}) 
+ \operatorname{cap}(S\cap T,\overline{S} \cap \overline{T}) 
+ \operatorname{cap}(S\cap T,\overline{T} \setminus \overline{S})
\\
&\le \operatorname{cap}(S\setminus T,\overline{S}\cap \overline{T}) 
+ \operatorname{cap}(S\cap T,\overline{S}\cap \overline{T}) 
+ \operatorname{cap}(T\setminus S,\overline{S}\cap \overline{T}) \\
&+ \operatorname{cap}(S\cap T,\overline{S} \setminus \overline{T}) 
+ \operatorname{cap}(S\cap T,\overline{S} \cap \overline{T}) 
+ \operatorname{cap}(S\cap T,\overline{T} \setminus \overline{S}) \\
&+ \color{red}{\operatorname{cap}(S\setminus T,\overline{S}\setminus \overline{T}) + \operatorname{cap}(T\setminus S,\overline{T}\setminus \overline{S})} 
\\
&= 
  \operatorname{cap}(S\setminus T,\overline{S}\setminus \overline{T})
+ \operatorname{cap}(S\setminus T,\overline{S}\cap \overline{T}) 
+ \operatorname{cap}(S\cap T,\overline{S} \setminus \overline{T}) 
+ \operatorname{cap}(S\cap T,\overline{S}\cap \overline{T}) \\
&+ \operatorname{cap}(T\setminus S,\overline{T}\setminus \overline{S}) 
+ \operatorname{cap}(T\setminus S,\overline{S}\cap \overline{T}) 
+ \operatorname{cap}(S\cap T,\overline{T} \setminus \overline{S}) 
+ \operatorname{cap}(S\cap T,\overline{S} \cap \overline{T}) 
\\
&= \operatorname{cap}(S,\overline S) + \operatorname{cap}(T,\overline {T})
\end{align}

This is a creative way to split the sets. I have not noticed that in one entry, capacities are adivitive with respect to disjoint sets, because I think that in both entries at the same time that isn't possible. Thank you very much!
